# how to prove elementary Kolmogorov inequality, when $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\leq \mathcal{M})=1$ for some real $\mathcal{M}>0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

I am trying to prove an inequality problem which is termed as 'elementary Kolmogorov inequality'. It looks like Markov inequality but a bit different -

> If $\mathcal {g}:[0, \infty]\to [0, \infty]$ is non-decreasing and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\leq \mathcal{M})=1$ for some real $\mathcal{M}>0$ then $$\mathcal{P}(|X|>\mathit{a})\ge \frac{(E(\mathcal{g}(|X|))- \mathcal{g}(\mathit{a}))}{\mathcal{M}}, \ \mathit{a}>0.$$

All I did, is as follows, $$E(\mathcal{g}(|X|)) \\= \sum_{\mathit{a}=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)> \mathit{a})\\=\mathit{a}\sum_{\mathit{a}=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)= \mathit{a})\\=\mathit{a}[1-\sum_{\mathit{a}=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\le \mathit{a})] \\ =\mathit{a}[\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\leq \mathcal{M})-\sum_{\mathit{a}=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\le \mathit{a})]\\ \Rightarrow \frac{E(\mathcal{g}(|X|))}{\mathit{a}}+\sum_{\mathit{a}=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\le \mathit{a})=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\leq \mathcal{M}) $$. 
I don't know whether I am going to the right direction of the proof and if I am wrong, I would like to learn alternate ways to prove this inequality

Also, I need to know -
(i) how to extract $\mathcal{M}$ at divisor.

(ii) Can we directly prove the inequality using $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\leq \mathcal{M})=1$?

(iii) the condition when the equality holds.

Any help or explanation is highly appreciated.
$-------------------------------------$

Second workout : by Markov inequality we have $$E(\mathcal{g}(|X|))\ge \mathit{a}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)> \mathit{a}) \\ \Rightarrow -E(\mathcal{g}(|X|))\le \mathit{-a}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)> \mathit{a}) \\ \Rightarrow -E(\mathcal{g}(|X|)) + \mathit{a}\le \mathit{-a}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)> \mathit{a})+ \mathit{a} \\ \Rightarrow -E(\mathcal{g}(|X|)) + \mathit{a}\le \mathit{a}[1-\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)> \mathit{a})\\ \Rightarrow \mathit{-a}\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\le \mathit{a})\le E(\mathcal{g}(|X|))  \mathit{-a}\\ \Rightarrow \mathcal{-P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\le \mathit{a})\le \frac{E(\mathcal{g}(|X|))}{\mathit{a}}+1 \\ \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{g}(|X|)\le \mathit{a}) + 1\ge \frac{-E(\mathcal{g}(|X|))}{\mathit{a}} \\ $$

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that almost surely
$$\begin{align}
g(|X|)&= g(|X|) 1_{|X|>a} + g(|X|)1_{|X|\leq a}\\
&\leq M 1_{|X|>a} + g(a)1_{|X|\leq a}\\
&\leq  M 1_{|X|>a} + g(a)
\end{align}
$$
hence almost surely $$\frac{g(|X|)-g(a)}M\leq 1_{|X|>a}$$ and taking expectations,
$$\frac{E[g(|X|)]-g(a)}M\leq P(|X|>a)$$